# Display different div element components when Toggle switch slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to have a toggle switch which if slide left a div content components pops up and on slide right a different div content pop up.How can I proceed?

**HTML CONTENT**

```
<form>
    <label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox" checked="true" />
        <div class="slider round"></div>
    </label>
</form>

<div id ="menu1">
    Menu 1 content
</div>
<div id ="menu2">
    Menu 2 content
</div>
```

**CSS CONTENT**

```
/* The switch - the box around the slider */
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

/* Hide default HTML checkbox */
.switch input {display:none;}

/* The slider */
.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

As you can see I want like if the toggle slides right content of div `id="menu1"` to be displayed and on slide left content of div `id="menu2"` be displayed.I want to have a toggle switch which if slide left a div content components pops up and on slide right a different div content pop up.How can I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it but you'll need jQuery. Basically, we hide `#menu2` with CSS as `display:none;` as default and then use JS to `.show` or `.hide` for each. Let me know if you have questions.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#toggle").click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $("#menu1").show();
      $("#menu2").hide();
    } else {
      $("#menu1").hide();
      $("#menu2").show();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
/* The switch - the box around the slider */

.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}


/* Hide default HTML checkbox */

.switch input {
  display: none;
}


/* The slider */

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}


/* Rounded sliders */

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#menu2 {
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" checked="true" />
        <div class="slider round"></div>
    </label>
</form>

<div id="menu1">
  Menu 1 content
</div>
<div id="menu2">
  Menu 2 content
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to implement the required functionality.

First, in order to uniquely identify your checkbox, define an `id` for it. Replace your HTML with the following. I have added `id="checkbox1"` for the checkbox.

```html
<form>
  <label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" checked="true" >
    <div class="slider round"></div>
  </label>
</form>

<div id ="menu1">
  Menu 1 conetnt
</div>
<div id ="menu2">
  MEnu 2 content
</div>
```

Next you need to add the following JavaScript code. Since your checkbox is `checked` by default, `menu2` will be hidden initially. The code below hides `menu2` initially and then toggles between `menu1` and `menu2` whenever the checkbox value changes.

```js
var checkbox1 = document.getElementById('checkbox1');
var menu1 = document.getElementById('menu1');
var menu2 = document.getElementById('menu2');

menu2.style.display = 'none';

checkbox1.onchange = function () {
  if (checkbox1.checked) {
    menu1.style.display = 'block';
    menu2.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    menu2.style.display = 'block';
    menu1.style.display = 'none';

  }
};
```